# HttpClient not responding properly with 5+ minutes response

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming, httpclient

I need to access a third party API using C# and HttpClient to retrive some data.
For some requests using parameter e.g `Template = 1`, the request works fine either on my C# code or Postman with a response between 1~3 minutes.

When I send a request with parameter e.g `Template = 2`, the average response time on Postman is 9 minutes and the response is properly retrieved. On my C# code, no matter the timeout I set for the request, for this same one the response is not retrieved.

I've created a POC using Node+Axios and the response is properly retrieved on both scenarios.

How can I handle this HttpClient particularity on C#??

```cs
public static async Task SendRequestPOC()
{
    var messageHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
    messageHandler.KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    messageHandler.KeepAlivePingPolicy = HttpKeepAlivePingPolicy.Always;
    messageHandler.KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    messageHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

    //I have tried both using messageHandler and not.
    var client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

    //I've tried using HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead and ResponseHeadersRead
    var getResponse = await client.GetAsync("http://myendpoint", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

    Console.WriteLine(await getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

I´ve tried some approaches such as using Sockets, where I created the HTTP request in a string and sent it to the API, but when waiting for the response with `socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None, CancellationToken)`, the application threw an error ("An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host") after two minutes of execution.

Also, I've tried a NetworkStream to write data on a similar way I did with sockets, but when waiting for the response with `stream.ReadAsync()`, the application threw a timeout exception due to the long time waiting.

I' ve tried another POC to simulate the same behavior where I created an API that performs an `await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromMinutes(12))` and responds to the C# application after this period. Running locally, there were no issues for the response to the C# application, but when I deployed this POC on an Azure VM, there was no response to the HttpClient call, throwing an exception due to timeout. Using NodeJS+Axios/Postman/Browser it worked successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working method that I use, with retries and try-catch. It is working very well in most scenarios to many different API:s. (Nevermind the CallContext class. It is just a class for handling current sessions. )

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> TryGetAsync<T>(CallContext callContext, string endPoint, string objectName, int timeoutInMilliseconds = 60000)
{
    var logPrefix = "TryGetAsync";
    var retryCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var sessionId = await _context.GetSessionAsync(callContext);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endPoint);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-SessionId", sessionId);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutInMilliseconds);

                var response = await client.GetAsync(endPoint);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"{response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }

                // To be able to handle metadata that starts with a $ character
                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var entities = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
                try
                {
                    entities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(content, settings);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw (new Exception($"Unable to deserialize response. (t={typeof(T)}, rawText={content})", ex));
                }
                return entities;
            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("(404) Not Found"))
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
            }

            var message = "";
            if (ex.Response == null)
            {
                message = "No response";
            }
            else
            {
                message = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
            var errText = $"{logPrefix} - WebException (message={message}, retryCount={retryCount}, uri={endPoint})";
            _log.Value.Write(new LogEvent(callContext, LogLevel.Fatal, ex, errText));

            if (retryCount > 3)
            {
                throw (new Exception(errText, ex));
            }

            retryCount++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception unhandledException)
        {
            string errText = $"{logPrefix} - Exception";
            _log.Value.Write(new LogEvent(callContext, LogLevel.Fatal, unhandledException, errText));
            throw (new Exception(errText, unhandledException));
        }
    }
}
```